# Stripe testing works only on localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend, stripe-payments, backend

Stripe testing payment works fine on localhost but when app is deployed to digital ocean testing doesn't work, I'm not getting clientSecret (code below) back.

And I am getting also this error :
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://e-keyboards.com/api/create-payment-intent' from origin 'http://www.e-keyboards.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Code from backend:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET)

exports.createPaymentIntent = async (req, res) => {

    const user = await User.findOne({email: req.user.email}).exec()

    const cart = await Cart.findOne({orderedBy: user._id}).exec()

    const {cartTotal} = cart

    console.log('CART TOTAL CHARGED', cart.cartTotal)
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: cartTotal * 100,
        currency: 'eur'
    })

    res.send({
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
        cartTotal,
    })
}
```

stripe route:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const {
    createPaymentIntent
} = require('../controllers/stripe')

const {
    authCheck
} = require('../middlewares/auth')
const { checkout } = require('./auth')

router.post('/create-payment-intent', authCheck, createPaymentIntent)

module.exports = router
```

frontend code:

```
 let {cart, user, checkout} = useSelector(state => ({...state})) 

    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const [processing, setProcessing] = useState('')
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true)
    const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState('')
    const [cartTotal, setCartTotal] = useState(0)


    const stripe = useStripe()
    const elements = useElements()
    const options = useOptions();

    useEffect(() => {
        createPaymentIntent(user.token)
        .then(res => {
            setClientSecret(res.data.clientSecret)
            setCartTotal(res.data.cartTotal)
        })
    }, [user.token])

    const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setProcessing(true)

        const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
          payment_method:{
            card: elements.getElement(CardNumberElement),
            billing_details: {
              name: e.target.name.value
            }
          }
        })

        if(payload.error){
          setError(`Payment failed ${payload.error.message}`)
        }else{
          console.log(JSON.stringify(payload, null, 4))
          createOrder(payload, user.token)
          .then(res => {
            if(res.data.ok){
              if(typeof window !== "undefined") localStorage.removeItem('cart')
              dispatch(emptyCart())
              dispatch(checkoutChange(false))
              localStorage.removeItem('checkout')
              empytUserCart(user.token)
              toast.success('Payment successfull!!')
            }
          })
          setError(null)
          setProcessing(false)
        }
    }
```

createPaymentIntent function:

```
export const createPaymentIntent = (authtoken) => axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/create-payment-intent`, 
    {},
    {
        headers: {
            authtoken
        }
    })
```

I added
"Content-Type": "text/plain",
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
to headers object in createPaymentIntent function but still getting error and still not getting res.data.clientSecret and res.data.cartTotal in react.
Again-everything works fine on localhost.Problems appear in deployed app.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch in the origins (specifically the domain names) you're using, and you haven't configured CORS to allow the origin mismatch.

Specifically, it looks like your page is being loaded from an origin of `http://www.e-keyboards.com` and is trying to make a request to `http://e-keyboards.com/api/create-payment-intent` which has a different origin (`http://e-keyboards.com`).  Check both your `process.env.REACT_APP_API` value as well as the URL(s) you're using to load the page.

If you switch everything to either `http://e-keyboards.com` *or* `http://www.e-keyboards.com` that should get things working.  You could also configure CORS to allow the cross-origin request, but it's probably easier to make the origins match.

Comment: I don't get previous error but still doesn't work.  Now I'm getting :"POST http://www.e-keyboards.com/api/create-payment-intent 504 (Gateway Time-out)"  and  "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 504
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)"

Comment: @Justin Can you please take a look at this question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66983230/9409877

Comment: I had a look, but it appears that question was resolved in the comments.  Glad to hear you got it working!